# Forward fill column one year after last observation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, resampling

I forward fill values in the following df using:

```
df = (df.resample('d') # ensure data is daily time series
 .ffill()
 .sort_index(ascending=True))
```

`df before forward fill`

```
id                 a          b          c          d
datadate                                              
1980-01-31        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
1980-02-29        NaN         2         NaN        NaN
1980-03-31        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
1980-04-30         1         NaN         3          4
1980-05-31        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
              ...        ...        ...        ...
2019-08-31        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
2019-09-30        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
2019-10-31        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
2019-11-30        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
2019-12-31        NaN        NaN        20         33
```

However, I wish to only forward fill one year after (date is datetime) the last observation and then the remaining rows simply be NaN. I am not sure what is the best way to introduce this criteria in this task. Any help would be super!

Thanks

Comment: *I am not sure what is the best way to introduce this criteria in this task.* please make sure :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to forward-fill the values on Dec 31, 2019 to the next year. Try this:

```
end_date = df.index.max()
new_end_date = end_date + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)
new_index = df.index.append(pd.date_range(end_date, new_end_date, closed='right'))

df = df.reindex(new_index)
df.loc[end_date:, :] = df.loc[end_date:, :].ffill()
```

Result:

```
              a    b     c     d
1980-01-31  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
1980-02-29  NaN  2.0   NaN   NaN
1980-03-31  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
1980-04-30  1.0  NaN   3.0   4.0
1980-05-31  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
2019-08-31  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
2019-09-30  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
2019-10-31  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
2019-11-30  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
2019-12-31  NaN  NaN  20.0  33.0
2020-01-01  NaN  NaN  20.0  33.0
2020-01-02  NaN  NaN  20.0  33.0
...
2020-12-31  NaN  NaN  20.0  33.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to forward fill using a limit parameter, but this wont handle the leap-year:

```
df.fillna(mehotd='ffill', limit=365)
```

The second solution is to define a more robust function to do the forward fill in the 1-year window:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffsets

def fun(serie_df):
    serie = serie_df.copy()
    indexes = serie[~serie.isnull()].index

    for idx in indexes:
        mask = (serie.index >= idx) & (serie.index < idx+DateOffset(years=1))
        serie.loc[mask] =  serie[mask].fillna(method='ffill')
    return serie

df_filled = df.apply(fun, axis=0)
```

If a column has multiple non-nan values in the same 1-year window, then the first fill will stop once the most recent value is encounter. The second solution will treat the consecutive value as if they were independent.